# .htaccess file location on server

Tags: htaccess

Because I am using a shared server (Apache 2.4) and don't have root access, I uploaded an .htaccess file. As best as I can determine, the .htaccess file is not stored in the public_html directory, where the file was initially transferred. There is a file in public_html named .htaccess_bak with content identical to the originally-loaded .htaccess, but not .htaccess.

Where on the server is the uploaded file ultimately stored? (I attempted to find the answer in Apache documentation, but without success.) I am also interest in learning how Apache physically handles the actual file, as distinguished from implementing the directives.

Comment: I've never heard of something moving .htaccess and leaving .htaccess_bak in its place.  That certainly not the way Apache usually works.   What operating system is this server running?   If linux, what flavor?    What is the hosting company?

Comment: Thanks.  The OS is LiteSpeed, a commercial variant of Apache 2.4.  I need to do some digging to figure this out - I beginning to wonder whether my existing .htaccess file is on the correct branch.

Comment: The domain name you registered with when you opened the hosting acount will be at public_html which is the root folder. Any other domain name you use as an addon will have a  folder under public_html, The first question is do you just have the one domain name or multiple. Each domain name has its own folder and its own instance of the .htaccess file in its own folder. What program are you using to access your host?

Comment: It turns out that after a server migration some time ago that the file was deleted (by me, of course). Thus the evidence was staring me in the face from the outset (in both cPanel & FileZilla) - .htaccess simply wasn't there, notwithstanding the presence of the file in a subdomain branch and the backup file on the root. I've now restored the file and solved the mystery.  Thank you all for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: What was confusing, was the "I uploaded an .htaccess file" statement. Which implies you've "just" uploaded the file, not that you uploaded the file "some time ago". I have encountered hosts that have renamed `.htaccess` files during a server upgrade when something in `.htaccess` was causing a fatal error. What do you mean by your last sentence: "I am also interest in learning how Apache physically handles the actual file, as distinguished from implementing the directives."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you indicate in the comments that you deleted the file and you were just confused.  You shouldn't need any more answers to the question.

Comment: Yes, thank you.   I assumed incorrectly that the .htaccess file was still there somewhere.   As I haven't dealt with it in some time, it was necessary to reacquaint myself with the file, it's directives, and placement.  I am planning to add another such file on a subdomain branch, so this was not wasted effort on my part.  Nevertheless, I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> Where on the server is the uploaded file ultimately stored?

The `.htaccess` file is a per-directory config file. The contents of it apply to the current directory and all subdirectories.

So, in order to apply to the `public_html` directory, it needs to be stored in the `public_html` directory. (It is also possible that it's stored in the *parent* directory - above the document root (in this instance) - but that is unlikely. The server would need to allow `.htaccess` overrides for the parent directory (unlikely) and some of the directives may need to be rewritten to allow for the difference in the directory-prefix.)

> There is a file in public_html named .htaccess_bak with content identical to the originally-loaded .htaccess

To echo what I said in comments, I have encountered (friendly) webhosts that have renamed `.htaccess` files during a server upgrade when something in `.htaccess` was causing a fatal error and the `.htaccess` file was not fundamental to the running of the site.

But otherwise, renaming `.htaccess` as `.htaccess_bak` is not a standard process, unless this is genuinely a "backup" made by some other service (a CMS perhaps).

> I am also interest in learning how Apache physically handles the actual file, as distinguished from implementing the directives

Not sure what you mean by this? Apache processes the `.htaccess` file at the start of the request, before it reaches your server-side scripts.